# Change Default Visibility in HTML page from Visible to Hidden using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

**I copied this code from the following [website](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/) (it's the last example before comments)**

I have a webpage with links that will `show/hide` hidden text on the page. Everything works great functionality wise, but the hidden text starts off as visible upon the page loading. What do I need to change in the script so that it starts off as hidden. I apologize for the naming conventions, not the best...

**JS :**

```
function showonlyonev2(thechosenone) {
      var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
      for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
            name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
            if (name == 'newboxes-2') {
                  if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                        if (newboxes[x].style.display == 'block') {
                              newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                        else {
                              newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
                        }
                  }else {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<li>
   <a id="myHeader1-2" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes1-2');"> John Doe</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a id="myHeader2-2" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes2-2');">Jane Doe</a>
</li>

<div class="newboxes-2" id="newboxes1-2">
   <p>Phone Number1</p>
</div>
<div class="newboxes-2" id="newboxes2-2">
   <p>Phone Number2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your divs in the html assign style display: none like this.

```
<div class="newboxes-n" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: perfect thank you! I assumed I would have to edit the Javascript but the answer was in the html.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you coulde avoid inline-events, you can use the power of jQuery and achieve that with simple code, check example below.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('body').on('click', 'li a', function(){
  var target_id = '#'+$(this).data('target');

  $('.newboxes-2:not('+target_id+')').hide(); //Hide all divs except the target

  $(target_id).toggle(); //Show/hide related one in every click
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a id="myHeader1-2" data-target="newboxes1-2" href="#"> John Doe</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a id="myHeader2-2" data-target="newboxes2-2" href="#">Jane Doe</a>
</li>
the hidden text:

<div class="newboxes-2" id="newboxes1-2" style="display:none">
  <p>Phone Number1</p>
</div>

<div class="newboxes-2 hidden" id="newboxes2-2" style="display:none">
  <p>Phone Number2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That you, this looks much cleaner. One added functionality of the "John/Jane Doe" buttons is they would show/hide themselves as well as each other. It was basically a toggle button. Jane could hide John or Jane, whoever was displayed at the time, and vice-versa.

Comment: Done, using `toggle()` function and `:not` selector check my update.